# Cloning javax.mail.Message and Cloning javax.mail.Multipart, Java 8

Tags: java-8, clone, multipart, mimebodypart

I'm implementing a mail Sender, near 1'6000.000 mails (with images and `PDF`) in one day per month (closing month extract), the mails are about 12 products...

I need to fill a Message Scratch per product... in order to not read (per email) else per product.

I'm trying to implement cloning `javax.mail.Message` and `javax.mail.Multipart` in order to be faster.

AddContent to Multipart

```
  public static void addContent(final Multipart multipart, String contenidoCorreo) throws Exception {
    MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new PreencodedMimeBodyPart("8bit");
    mimeBodyPart.setText(contenidoCorreo, "iso-8859-1", "html");
    multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart, 0);
  }
```

Add Image per Bytes

```
  public static void addImageToMultipart(final Multipart multipart, byte[] contenidoImagen, String nombreImagen) throws Exception {
    MimeBodyPart imagenMimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    try {
      ByteArrayDataSource byteArrayDataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(contenidoImagen, "image/*");
      imagenMimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(byteArrayDataSource));
      imagenMimeBodyPart.setFileName(nombreImagen);
      imagenMimeBodyPart.setContentID("<" + nombreImagen + ">");
      imagenMimeBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
      multipart.addBodyPart(imagenMimeBodyPart);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

AddPDF per File

```
  public static void addPDF(final Multipart multipart, String ruta, String nombre) throws Exception {
    Path path = Paths.get(ruta, nombre);
    if (path.toFile().exists()) {
      MimeBodyPart preencodedMimeBodyPart = new PreencodedMimeBodyPart("base64");
      preencodedMimeBodyPart.attachFile(path.toFile());
      preencodedMimeBodyPart.setFileName(nombre);
      preencodedMimeBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
      preencodedMimeBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
      multipart.addBodyPart(preencodedMimeBodyPart);

      MimeBodyPart pdfMimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  }
```

My Cloning Message

```
  public static Message cloneMessage(Message source) {
    //Multiple and Separated Exceptions because maybe not all properties are defined in some time.
    Message target = new MimeMessage(source.getSession());
    try {
      if (source.getFrom() != null && source.getFrom().length > 0) {
        Address address = (source.getFrom()[0]);
        target.setFrom(new InternetAddress(((InternetAddress) address).getAddress(), ((InternetAddress) address).getPersonal()));
      }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      //Handle Exception
    }
    try {
      target.setSentDate((Date) (source.getSentDate().clone()));
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
      //Handle Exception
    }

    try {
      target.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, target.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO).clone());
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
      //Handle Exception
    }

    try {
      Enumeration numerationHeaders = source.getAllHeaders();
      while (numerationHeaders.hasMoreElements()) {
        Header header = (Header) numerationHeaders.nextElement();
        target.addHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
      }
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
      //Handle Exception
    }

    try {
      target.setSubject(new String(source.getSubject()));
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
      //Handle Exception
    }
    try {
      target.setContent(cloneMultipart((Multipart)(source.getContent())));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      //Handle Exception
    }
    return target;
  }
```

Cloning Multipart

```
  public static Multipart cloneMultipart(Multipart source) {
    MimeMultipart target = new MimeMultipart();
    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < source.getCount(); i++) {
        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = (MimeBodyPart)source.getBodyPart(i);
        mimeBodyPart //?????
      }
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
      //Handle Exception
    }
    return target;
  }
```

**How cloning Multipart?**

**some advice to clone Message?**

How detect the Content (the used with `addContent` method) has been added?